# Загрузка изображения из assets. Отличие методов getAssets().open(filename) и mAssetManager.open(filename)

Tags: java, android

Имею класс наследуемый от SurfaceView . Нужно загрузить изображение из assets . Выполнить это InputStream ims = getAssets().open(filename); не представляется возможным так как  getAssets метод AppCompatActivity. Увидел, где то вот такой код
 InputStream  ims = mAssetManager.open(filename);  и он работает . Объясните пожалуйста как для человека, который плохо знает основы java, правильно ли я понимаю , что это методы которые имеют одну и ту же цель, но просто расположены в разных классах?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

См. документацию и исходный код ОС, метод getAssets() возвращает как раз AssetManager которому уже принадлежит open(), так что это одно и то же, но второе может применяться, когда нужно сперва получить AssetManager, затем куда-то его передать и там получить из него конкретные ассеты, например при взаимодействии Java-JNI.